# C++ What is the best way to add an element at the end of a vector?

Tags: c++

As the title states, what would the best way to do this?

Currently I have a function:

```
void addElemEnd(){
   myvect.push_back();
}
```

Doing it this way doesn't work, also would there be a better way to do this aside using the `push_back()` function?

Comment: doesnt work how?

Comment: What are you adding?

Comment: `myvect.push_back();` without a value?? What do you expect to be added?

Comment: The best way is to [read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) first:

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because **you are tying to call the method push_back() without any parameter**.

The correct way is to call the method passing the element to add (of course)!

```
 int myint = 5;
 myvector.push_back (myint);
```

Comment: Someone needs some easy rep ;)

Comment: @Treycos I would be embarrassed asking this kind of questions! ;)

Comment: @granmirupa Wouldn't we all be? But anyhow the answer is correct, valid, and far politer than what I would have written, so all the power to you :)

Comment: @ChrisBritt Stay cool, calm, and collected. That's the way :)